# How to handle the inner LI click of a nested list

Tags: jquery, html, css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/34ng9sto/14/

JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $(".uSPInner").hide();

    //modify the "hover" to "click" and merge with thesecond "click" function. SlideToggle only if a child UL exist within the parent UL
    $(".clickMe").closest("li").hover(function () {
        $(this).closest("li").find("ul").slideDown();
    }, function () {
        $(this).closest("li").find("ul").slideUp();
    });
    $('.clickMe').click(function () {
        alert("outer clicked");
        $('.clickMe').removeAttr('id');
        $(this).attr('id', 'current');
        $('.dispArtBody').addClass('hideContent');
        var element = $(this).attr("data-toggle");
        $(element).removeClass('hideContent');
    });

    $('.uSPInner').click(function () { //if the inner LI is clicked, set the inner clicked LI ID to "current" and also the parent LI ID to "current"
        alert("inner clicked");
    });
    $('.uSPStyle li a').filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).html()) == '';
    }).parent().hide();
    $('.uSPInner li a').filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).html()) == '';
    }).parent().hide();
});
```

What I am looking to do is

- Instead of hover, expand the sub UL, handle it with click and merge
  with the second click event.
- When the sub UL LI is clicked, set that to "current", as well as the
  parent of the sub UL LI that was clicked.

Comment: Sorry I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a better solution for that, but for the momen this could help you:

```
$('.clickMe').click(function () {

    var $this = $(this);

    $this.closest("li").find("ul").slideToggle();

    $('.clickMe').removeClass('current');

    $this.addClass('current');
    $this.parents('.uSPInner').siblings('.clickMe').addClass('current');

});
```

Instead of the in and out handler of the hover-function, just use the `slideToggle()`-function within the click-event.

Note: I changed the ID `current` to a class because when you want to apply it to multiple elements have to remember that ID have to be unique in the document.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/11pyk68y/)**

---

Additon:

I would recommend to set the class `uSPInner` to

```
.uSPInner{
    display: none;
}
```

instead of hiding it via jQuery on page-load.

Comment: This is great, except the "current" LI is not highlighted when the page first loads.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge What should be the current li on pageload ?

Comment: change it to <a class="tfLink clickMe current" instead of id=current

Comment: I think I know what is happening, I am trying to set the same ID to multiple LI at the same time which is causing the issue. Instead I can set it to class. By default SECTION 1 should be the current and then based on click it should. Everything else works except the on page load it's not :)

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge I updated my answer, have a look at the demo

Comment: @empiric Thank you. Adding the class also works. But I will take a look at your solution too. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. That actually did the trick :) Here is the final fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/11pyk68y/1/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of targeting the `li` element you must select the `a` element and use `slideToggle()` function to toggle between open and close states:

```
$(function () {
    $(".uSPInner").hide();   
    $(".clickMe").click(function () {
        $(this).closest("li").find("ul").slideToggle();
    });    
    $('.uSPStyle li a').filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).html()) == '';
    }).parent().hide();
    $('.uSPInner li a').filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).html()) == '';
    }).parent().hide();
});
```